# How to make a plugin work on refresh? (Nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to use the vue GAPI plugin in a project.

It works fine when navigating between pages, but on refresh I get the error:

`vue-gapi.common.js?15fd:241 Uncaught (in promise) Error: gapi not initialized at GoogleAuthService.isSignedIn (vue-gapi.common.js?15fd:241)`

I think this is due to the way I am initialising the component in my project - namely through the /plugins folder. I think I am trying to use GAPI before it is loaded, but even when wrapping a call to GAPI in a promise, it immediately rejects with the above error. What would be the proper way to handle this? Below is the code for my gapi plugin:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueGAPI from "vue-gapi";
const apiConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  clientId:
    "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  discoveryDocs: [
    "https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest",
    "https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/slides/v1/rest"
  ],
  scope:
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly",
  refreshToken: true
};
Vue.use(VueGAPI, apiConfig);
```

nuxt.config.js has the following:

```
  plugins: [
    { src: "~plugins/gapi.js", ssr: false },
  ],
```

Any advice on how to get this working is very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you utilizing your `gapi`?

Comment: If it occurs on reload, it means it's a SSR problem. As your plugin is only client side, it won't be initialized on server side. So when you call the `gapi` object, be sure to wrap it with conditions so that it's only called on client side!

Comment: Hi both

Thanks - I am not sure that is the issue

```beforeMount () {
   console.log( this.$isSignedIn(),'signin?');
},```


results in a rejected promise if refreshing but not if browsing from another route. 
beforeMount is a client-side hook so I think the issue is the plugin itself not waiting for auth with Google to resolve successfully?

Thanks

Comment: Given the plugin runs on every page load in the app I would assume browsing between pages works as the auth has had time to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping the call to this.$isSignedIn() in a promise which makes a few attempts to resolve this.$isSignedIn() and on success sets a data prop on my component. This then acts as the trigger for other things to happen as the sign in is 'complete' at this point.

Could not find another way to do it without modifying the NPM.